# A tcbline only to the half of the page

Tags: tcolorbox, tikz-styles, tcbset

This MWE example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}[
    sharp corners, breakable, frame hidden, enhanced, boxrule=0pt,
    borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{green},
    colback=green!10,
    segmentation code={\draw[black, dashed, line width=1pt]($(segmentation.west)$)--($(segmentation.west)+(4,0)$);}] % Ende der Einstellungen
    test
    \tcbline
    xx
    \tcblower
    test
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Produces this outcome

[image]

I wish, that both lines, the `\tcbline`  and `\tcblower`  are like `\tcblower`  (the shorter line). How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
sharp corners, 
breakable, 
enhanced, 
toprule=0pt,
bottomrule=0pt,
rightrule=0pt,
leftrule=3pt,
colframe=green,
colback=green!10,
segmentation style={shorten >=8cm,dashed,black,line width=1pt},
]
test
\tcbline
xx
\tcblower
test
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Edit: make the line in the center

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
sharp corners, 
breakable, 
enhanced, 
toprule=0pt,
bottomrule=0pt,
rightrule=0pt,
leftrule=3pt,
colframe=green,
colback=green!10,
segmentation style={shorten >=4cm,shorten <=4cm,dashed,black,line width=1pt},
]
test
\tcbline
xx
\tcblower
test
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you, that is a huge help!!! One additional follow up question. Is it also possible, that the black line appears in the middle (centered) of the tcolorbox?

Comment: @montarenbici using `shorten >=4cm,shorten <=4cm,` instead?

Comment: Thank you!!! You just literally saved my day, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @montarenbici You're welcome.